# Apache Cassandra - Column-Value Timeline

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm looking to store time series data in an Apache Cassandra instance

I've read [the guides from DataStax](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra) but unfortunately they are from 2012. However I think the underlying principles still apply - I just want to know how to do it with the most recent version of Cassandra (v3.11).

I have a table currently like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS tick_data
WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                    'replication_factor': 1};

USE tick_data;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS minute_bars (
contract_id text,
bar_time timestamp,
bar text,
PRIMARY KEY (contract_id, bar_time)
);
```

After inserting some data and connecting via `cqlsh` I can view the data and the first few rows look like this:

```
 contract_id | bar_time                        | bar
-------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           1 | 2017-07-21 14:05:00.000000+0000 |     {'open': 0.15, 'high': 0.15, 'low': 0.15, 'close': 0.15, 'volume': -1, 'barCount': -1}
           1 | 2017-07-21 14:10:00.000000+0000 |     {'open': 0.15, 'high': 0.15, 'low': 0.15, 'close': 0.15, 'volume': -1, 'barCount': -1}
           1 | 2017-07-21 14:15:00.000000+0000 |     {'open': 0.15, 'high': 0.15, 'low': 0.15, 'close': 0.15, 'volume': -1, 'barCount': -1}
           1 | 2017-07-21 14:20:00.000000+0000 |     {'open': 0.15, 'high': 0.15, 'low': 0.15, 'close': 0.15, 'volume': -1, 'barCount': -1}
           1 | 2017-07-21 14:25:00.000000+0000 |     {'open': 0.15, 'high': 0.15, 'low': 0.15, 'close': 0.15, 'volume': -1, 'barCount': -1}
           1 | 2017-07-21 14:30:00.000000+0000 |     {'open': 0.15, 'high': 0.15, 'low': 0.15, 'close': 0.15, 'volume': -1, 'barCount': -1}
```

Which is very distinct from what I expected: [image]

**In order to get the benefits of Apache Cassandra when working with time series data, what is the most up-to-date procedure for storing timeline data?**

Answer (score 0):

in CQL you will see only tables as you do (have a closer look at the coloring, see below). One "flaw" in your design is not to use buckets - all data for one contract is stored on one node (as you are using replication factor of one):

```
PRIMARY KEY (contract_id, bar_time)
```

In cassandra a primary key is composed of two parts - partition key and often clustering columns. You did choose `contract_id` as partition key, which means all inserts for a specific contract will be one one node only. As updates seem to occur all 5 minutes you will end up with very wide rows, approx. 9000 timestamps per month.

To benefit of buckets in your case

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS minute_bars (
    contract_id text,
    bucket date, 
    bar_time timestamp,
    bar text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((contract_id, bucket), bar_time)
);
```

Now the partition key (which decides where to put your data) is composed of `contract_id` and `bucket`, this is noted by putting both in brackets. You could make buckets for every day or one per month for example depending on your needs) and store all data for one day or a month in one bucket. If you select your table in cqlsh you will see the difference in coloring the column headers.

If you would store per day

```
SELECT bar_time, bar_text FROM minute_bars WHERE contract_id=1 and date="2017-07-01";
```

will give you all data for contract 1 and 2017-07-01 with a single request and no restrictions on bar_time. If you store like this and need a complete month you need to select all days per single request, which will also perform well as multiple nodes can process your data if you do those calls asynchronuos.